# Ajax.BeginForm absolute url MVC CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any way to get the Ajax.BeginForm to output a absolute url rather than just a relative one?

I am trying to get some forms working with CORS on a site hosted on another server. 
At the moment I am parsing the form with jquery onsuccess in the ajax options.

I am not any pointers to a tutorial on writing an extension for it would be handy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the Ajax.BeginForm to output a absolute url
>   rather than just a relative one?

Yes, but you need to specify the `Url` in the `AjaxOptions` and not use the overload which takes action and controller names:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { Url = Url.Action("Foo", "Bar", null, "http") }))
{
    ...
}
```

`Url.Action` has an overload where you could specify the protocol to be used which generates absolute urls. And if you wanted to use the same protocol as the one used to request the current action instead of hardcoding it you could use the following:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { Url = Url.Action("Foo", "Bar", null, Request.Url.Scheme) }))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to roll it more like this to include the htmloptions but that worked perfectly using (Ajax.BeginForm( null,null,new AjaxOptions { Url = Url.Action("SubmitAdult", "FallsAssessment", null, Request.Url.Scheme), HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "closeModal", OnSuccess = "success", OnFailure = "error" }, new { class = "form-inline", id = "FallsForm" }))

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { 
    Url = "http://www.domain.com/whatever" ,
    Confirm = "...",
    // and other options...
}))
{
    // html controls or helpers here...
}
```