# How to set action to External URL in Ajax.BeginForm with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, ajax.beginform

I want to set action External Service (e.g: https://someservice.com/SaveMessage). However BeginForm function expects Controller and Function name.

I want to set action for different domain(URL) and different controller. I **DO NOT** want to set action for same domain.

AjaxBeginForm as follows:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveContactMessage", "Ticket",
new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnBegin = "ticket.contactMessageSaveBegin",
    OnSuccess = "ticket.contactMessageSaveSuccess",
    OnFailure = "ticket.contactMessageSaveFailure"
}, new
{
    @class = "contact-form",
    id = "contact-form"
}))
{

//  Some Form Inputs

}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18308760/728795 . Not closing as a dupe yet as I am not 100% sure

Comment: When I try to solution following attribute has been included to form tag data-ajax-url="https://someservice.com/SaveMessage://localhost/foo/getFoo"

Comment: When I set foo, getFoo as null: data-ajax-url="https://someservice.com/SaveMessage://localhost/"

Comment: @Andrei  The answer that you suggest is for the same domain(URL) but different controller and function. I want to set for different domain(URL) and different controller

Comment: You can add the `Url` option to your `AjaxOptions()` like: `Url = "https://someservice.com/SaveMessage"`

Comment: @RahulSharma Request can ben sent to external URL but CORS issue shown up. I searched some SO topic but there is no solution for Ajax BeginForm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax.BeginForm absolute url MVC CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965171/ajax-beginform-absolute-url-mvc-cors)

Comment: No @LazZiya I found that answer it did not work for me. I want to set action for different BaseURL (domain). Your suggestion is for same BaseURL (Domain)